# ADS1256 Python Libraries

Tags: gpio, python, pi-3, hardware

So the other day I got myself a Waveshare High Precision AD/DA Expansion Board for my Pi-3.  The ADC on the board is an ADS1256, and I am having trouble finding code libraries to use with it.

Previously I was working with an MCP3008 (I am testing this board out because of the increase in precision for voltage measurements) and GPIOZero was a great library for that chip.  However I looked at the GPIOZero API and the ADS1256 doesn't seem supported, unless of course I missed that.

So does anyone have any Python libraries for the ADS1256 that they'd recommend?

Answer (score 3):

I was also digging a little bit on this kind of ADC! After finding this board, turned that I accidentally found this library: 
https://github.com/ul-gh/PiPyADC

It's interesting because it's an open project and the authors are still working in order to improve it.

Hope it helps you! =)